# Python multiprocessing with a FORTRAN executable

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using `multiprocessing` in `Python` to speed up the worker function which calls an `FORTRAN` executable. The code works when I set `processes=1`. Thus, I suspect something was wrong with the `multiprocessing` step. The error message I got is related to the `FORTRAN` step, `forrtl: severe (47): write to READONLY file, unit 50, file: TEMP2549429.DAT`, where `TEMP2549429.DAT` is the output file. I checked that file, and everything looks fine.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

**Main Function** just call the worker and I am using a `dictionary` (`return_dict`) to store returned results from worker functions.

```
import multiprocessing

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=20)
total_iter = 200

for dict_index in range(total_iter):
    pool.apply_async(worker_Call, args=(arg_A, arg_B, return_dict,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

**Worker Function** runs a `FORTRAN` exe which takes a plain text input file and writes results to a different text file. The function first generates a random number to make sure `inputs`, `outputs`, and `exe` have different names among workers

```
worker_Call(arg_A, arg_B, return_dict):

    random_extension = str(np_random_integers(1, 10000000))

    fn_input  = FN_INPUT % random_extension
    fn_output = FN_OUTPUT % random_extension
    FORTRAN_exe = FN_EXE.split(".exe")[0]+random_extension+".exe"

    # write input file
    file(fn_input, "wb").write(input)
    # copy and rename exe
    shutil.copy(FN_EXE, FORTRAN_exe)

    # call the function
    subprocess.call([FORTRAN_exe, fn_input, fn_output], shell=False)

    # load results
    parsed_leggett_return = np_genfromtxt(fn_output, dtype=np_float64, usecols=(3,4,5))

    return_dict[dict_index] = {"results": parsed_leggett_return} 
    return (return_dict)
```

Comment: Is it possible that your random generated a collision?  Does it work with, say, two workers?  You might also consider using the `tempfile` module - it'll help you avoid those collisions if that is in fact what's causing trouble.

Comment: @g.d.d.c, I tried different seeds and I do not think file collision is an issue although the error message looks like one. The `FORTRAN` program expects an input file and will always save an output file to the hard drive. Do you think `tempfile` can handle this scenario?